# How to set maven to build in a specific folder in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a spring boot based project that is hosted on a google drive shared folder that is helping me and my team to work together in real time.

I want to change the default target directory so when I do run my project my team mates don't have to synchronize for a build but only synchronize my coding.

I did some research but what I tried didn't work here is my base build maven

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <directory>c:/myProject</directory>
    <outputDirectory>c:/myProject/classes</outputDirectory>

</build>
```

But this is not working and maven says that he is enable to find the main class

the default maven configuration is a s below

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What should I do so this target goes to c:/myProject

Comment: As I know you can exclude folder from google drive synchronization it could be maybe better approach than changing output path.

Comment: These are the maven defaults `<project>...<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>...` from the [super pom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) ... and can be overwritten by individual pom ...this is a very "hard switch", I think, which should affect all (not too fancy) plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fix the problem of the main class with this plugin:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR file -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>
                 <mainClass>pacakgeAndClasseName</mainClass>
              </manifest>
          </archive>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

And instead of `C:/myProject`, try  `C:\\myProject`  and `C:\myProject`

- If the first solution did not work you can use this plugin:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>yourPath</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```